# Modify MR merge commit message through Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

In order to introduce a proper workflow for our team in Azure DevOps, I am trying to find a way to set the merge commit message of a merge request to the title of the merge request. For some reason, Azure DevOps sets the merge commit message by default to `Merged PR#: <title>`, adding an undesired prefix to the message. This beheviour cannot be customized, as described in [this (5-year old) issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Change-default-title-for-pull-request-co/365716) in *Microsoft Developer Community*. Recently, someone [suggested](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Change-default-title-for-pull-request-co/365716#T-N10292996) in this thread to use Azure DevOps's API from a build pipeline to set a customized message. I have tried with success to reach the API from my pipeline, but I cannot find a way to have my custom message be registered in Azure DevOps.

When I send a request with the proper merge options (as described in [this piece of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#gitpullrequestcompletionoptions)), the API returns the updated pull request information.

For example, when I send a request with this body :

```json
{
    "completionOptions": {
        "mergeStrategy": "squash",
        "mergeCommitMessage": "something"
    }
}
```

the API properly returns the pull request data :

```json
{
    <...PR data...>
    "completionOptions": {
        "mergeCommitMessage": "something",
        "squashMerge": true,
        "mergeStrategy": "squash"
    }
    <...more PR data...>
}
```

so I assume the message has been updated. But when I go to my pending merge request on Azure DevOps, the message is the same as before:
[PR merge commit message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIvO9.png)

When I untick the "Customize merge commit message" box and proceed with the merge, the behaviour is the same and my customized message (with is basically the merge request title) is not kept.

Am I missing some additional information to put in the request ? Or does the web interface of Azure DevOps overwrite my options for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `completionOptions` is applied only when you set the PR to be auto completed.

You need to add this to your body:

```
"autoCompleteSetBy":  {
    "id":  "7a9a9b44-a2f1-6dfd-a7f6-54354353453"
 }
```

The "id" should be the user who created the PR - Project Build User Account.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your solution, but I encounter the following error : `Invalid pull request auto complete set by id. Valid values are either the current user identity id, or an empty guid (to unset auto complete).` It seems that I need to use the ID of the build account, but the variable `Build.QueuedBy` contains `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS` and using `Build.QueuedById` raises the same error. The proper permissions are set for the build account.

Comment: did you put the id of who created the PR?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I finally managed to make it work by choosing the `originId` of our project's build account !

Comment: Great! so the id should be the if of the project's build account?

Comment: Yes, when calling the API from the pipeline, using `System.AccessToken` for authentication.

Comment: @Ebig I updated the answer :) I glad it working for you.

Comment: @Ebig, where di you get that originId from?

Comment: @TheFool I made a request to DevOps API with the following URL: `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<your organisation>/_apis/graph/users?api-version=7.0-preview`, then I searched for my project's Build Account and looked up its `originId`. If I am not mistaken. You can make the request from your browser while connected to DevOps, or via Postman (or something alike) using Basic Auth and a valid token.

Comment: @Ebig, thanks for getting back! Yes, I also found that out by now. Regarding auth, I have supplied a `Bearer` token that I have obtained form `az account get-access-token`.

Comment: That same id exists as pullrequest.createdBy.id but I am getting the same eror. You have to get the pullrequest via api